# Magento 1 - Override block in module

Tags: magento-1.9, blocks

Is their any way we can override this block

**app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/Create/Items/Grid.php**

into module ?

**Config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <vendor_module>
            <version>
                0.1.0
            </version>
        </vendor_module>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <adminhtml>
                <rewrite>
                    <sales_order_create_items_grid>
                        Vendor_Module_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Create_Items_Grid
                    </sales_order_create_items_grid>
                </rewrite>
            </adminhtml>
        </blocks>
    </global>
</config>
```

**Vendor/Module/Block/Adminhtml/Sales/Order/Create/Items/Grid.php**

```
<?php

class Vendor_Moduley_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Create_Items_Grid extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Create_Items_Grid
{
    /**
     * Flag to check can items be move to customer storage
     *
     * @var bool
     */
    protected $_moveToCustomerStorage = true;

    /**
     * Class constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->setId('sales_order_create_search_grid');
    }

    /**
     * Returns the items
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getItems()
    {
        echo'check'; exit;
    }
}
```